# Interpretation of box-counting method from R

Tags: r, machine-learning, fractal

I tried to calculate the fractal dimension of a dataset using the box-counting method with R programming.

I used two packages:

The first one is `fractaldim`, specifically, the function `fd.estim.boxcount`.

The second one is `Rdimtools`, particularly the function `est.boxcount`.

The dataset utilized is

```
D <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-
                 databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin 
                 /wdbc.data", sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I only used the numeric variables without standardization.

After that, I got the following plots from the first and second package respectively

[image: using fd.estim.boxcount]

[image: using est.boxcount]

I am not really sure about how to interpret the results of using these two packages.

Any ideas or example are appreciated?

**Notes**

I can edit the question for more details if you want.

This is not homework, I am just trying to understand the idea of fractal dimension using the box-counting practically.